# Making a certain branch (not master) be the first branch on my github repository

Tags: github

When people click on Cataclysm-DDA on my profile (https://github.com/DanielPBak?tab=repositories), they are directed to my master branch, but I'd rather they be directed to a different branch (washboard_batch) where I've actually done some work.

I'd like to do this without changing the default branch. The only thing I want to change is the branch that a visitor is initially directed towards.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your default branch is named master. If you have admin rights over a
>   repository on GitHub, you can change the default branch on the
>   repository.

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/

Comment: I'd like not to change the default repository, since that will change commit and PR behaviour. Really, the *only* thing I want to change is the behaviour of my github page with 0 side-effects.

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak, as far as I know the only way to do that is to change the default branch, as Pankaj suggests.